# EJB injection with dynamically loaded classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb

I'm experimenting with loading classes at run-time and I'm curious, is it possible for @EJB annotated properties to be injected when classes are loaded in this manner? The class is being loaded from a servlet using the servlet's classloader (*ChangeAwareClassLoader*).

That is, if I load a class defined as

```
public class Foo {
  @EJB
  Bar bar;
}
```

in the servlet as follows

```
ClassLoader cLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
c = cLoader.loadClass("Foo");
```

I would like for the EJB *Bar* to be injected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJB's can only be injected with `@EJB` into "managed" classes. In Java EE, this basically means only into EJBs (Stateless and Stateful EJBs, Message Beans, etc.) and Servlets/Filters.

Anything else (POJOs, JPA entities, etc.) will not have the resources injected, and you'll have to use the lookup mechanism to get access to them.

Comment: I guess I was hoping there would be a way to "force" a pojo to be treated as a managed class.